# Query AD to find all the Computer in an OU with TC in their Name

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to search AD for all machines in a given OU that have 'TC' in their name, this is what I have so far, but its returning all machines, I need it to return just the machines with 'TC' in their name.

```
$root = ([adsi]'LDAP://OU=PCs,OU=Student Computers,DC=student,DC=belfastmet,DC=int','objectCategory=computer')
$searcher = new-object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($root)
$searcher.filter = "(objectCategory=computer)"
$searcher.pageSize=1000
$searcher.propertiesToLoad.Add("name")
$computers = $searcher.findall()
$computers | foreach {$_.properties.name}
```

Not really sure what I should be doing from this point, I am a Powershell Newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options. You can get all computers and then filter using Powershell cmdlets, or your ldap filter reflects what you want (better). Try this:

```
$searcher.filter = "(&(objectCategory=computer)(cn=TN*))"
```

With ActiveDirectoryModule, you could find machines in a specific OU using filter and limit the search to the OU (assuming YourDomain.com\YourOU in the example below) you want with SearchBase:

```
$adcomputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {name -like "TC*"} -Searchbase "OU=YourOU,DC=YourDomain,DC=com"
```

Comment: Great, How would i go about this using Get-ADComputer?

Comment: If you already have ActiveDirectory Module available to you, you do not need to bother with .NET search. @alroc already mentioned it, I will update the answer for alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [AD module](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx) available to you, you can do this with a single cmdlet.

`get-adcomputer -filter {name -like "*TC*"}`